# Chamilo Install Memory Error: Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, installation, cpanel

On a cPanel installation I installed Chamilo and am getting the following error as seen below.

I reviewed the PHP.ini file and it was set to 64M, I increased it to 128M. This didnt fix the problem.

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32 bytes) in [$ our path]/education/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Schema/AbstractAsset.php on line 170

Comment: you can use setmemory limit

Comment: Looks like you have an endless loop.

Comment: @NavnitMishra The OP already wrote that this has been done. What is the sense of your remark?

Comment: Is there something overwriting the memory limit? It's failing trying to allocate 33mb - which was below the initla limit of 64mb.

Comment: contact with you host provider

Answer (score 0):

Chamilo might use more than 32MB to load some specific pages (in particular reporting pages or scripts never loaded before). On *average* it will use only about 22MB per page for version 1.10, for example.

The error message you are seeing specifically indicates that there is still an active 32MB memory limit.

If you already changed it in php.ini, it is likely (on a cPanel install) that some .htaccess file will override this limit and set it back to 32MB. Depending on where your Chamilo root directory is located, this .htaccess file might be, for example, in /public_html/.htaccess if your Chamilo directory is in /public_html/chamilo/. (.htaccess files do modify the settings for all directories *under* their location).

.htaccess limits should look like this:

```
php_flag memory_limit 32M
```

Alternatively, something *above* your cPanel (WHM is a frequent companion to cPanel) might prevent cPanel to actually set the memory_limit. You might have access to the platform controlling your cPanel or not. If not, you should contact your hosting provider and ask them to put that limit higher.

If you manage thousands of students, the memory consumption might go as high as 256MB for some reports, so ask them directly to change that limit to that.

If you are using a development version of Chamilo, memory consumption might go much higher because of the use of memory-hungry Symfony components.